# Why does a left join return differently to a NOT IN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following query is behaving somewhat strangely:

```
SELECT #batches.OutTo, PO_Number, CONVERT(varbinary, #batches.OutTo) , convert     (varbinary, PO_Number), 
    CASE WHEN convert(varbinary, #batches.OutTo) NOT IN (SELECT convert(varbinary,    PO_Number) FROM #pos) 
         THEN 'NOT IN' ELSE 'IN' END
FROM #batches LEFT JOIN #pos ON 
    convert(varbinary, #batches.OutTo) = CONVERT(varbinary, PO_Number)
WHERE #batches.OutTo IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY #batches.OutTo, #pos.PO_Number


OutTo       PO_Number   (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
311117      NULL        0x333131313137      NULL                    IN
311130      311130      0x333131313330      0x333131313330          IN
311259      NULL        0x333131323539      NULL                    IN
L001934     L001934     0x4C303031393334    0x4C303031393334        IN
L001988     NULL        0x4C303031393838    NULL                    IN
L002002     NULL        0x4C303032303032    NULL                    IN
```

As you can see, the left join behaves correctly, but the NOT IN does not, returning IN for values that should be NOT IN. Why is this? Is it a bug, or a feature of SQL I don't know about?

Comment: If #batches.OutTo is nullable then you should use a LEFT JOIN or, preferably, NOT EXISTS. NOT IN is an improper construct when NULLs are involved because of how SQL uses IN to perform equality comparisons with NULLs (SQL Server has to say "unknown" when you ask if a value <> NULL).

Comment: You're correct - I just returned to edit my question and found that you had already answered it. The relevant resource I found (for anyone who stumbles across this question) is http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (you dont need subquery):

```
SELECT #batches.OutTo, PO_Number, CONVERT(varbinary(35), #batches.OutTo) , 
    convert     (varbinary(35), PO_Number), 
    CASE WHEN convert(varbinary(35), PO_Number) IS NULL THEN 'NOT IN' 
         ELSE 'IN' END

FROM #batches 
LEFT JOIN #pos ON 
    convert(varbinary(35), #batches.OutTo) = CONVERT(varbinary(35), PO_Number)
WHERE #batches.OutTo IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY #batches.OutTo, #pos.PO_Number
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the subquery `SELECT convert(varbinary,    PO_Number) FROM #pos` without any filter conditions, which I believe is resulting into additional values and making it to return as `IN` as values may be present in the list.

To fix the issue, I think you need to add the appropriate where clause in the subquery as well e.g.:

```
   SELECT convert(varbinary,    PO_Number) FROM #pos 
                          WHERE #batches.OutTo IS NOT NULL
```